# Upgrading with WiX Burn does not run upgrade custom actions on individual msi's

Tags: wix, windows-installer

EDIT: My custom actions seem to be running well now, but I don't believe I changed any code. Do custom actions run in the order they appear in the wxs file or is their execution order arbitrary?

If I build my product.msi version 1.0.0 and install it, then rebuild it to be product.msi version 1.0.1 and upgrade it, the custom actions get called perfectly.

If I build my product.msi version 1.0.0 and put it into a burn installer version 1.2.0 and install it, then rebuild product.msi version 1.0.1 and put it into burn installer version 1.2.1 and upgrade it, my custom actions do not get called correctly.

Something about the burn bootstrapper is making custom actions not perform identically.

Here are my 4 custom actions. The final two are not being called when running the bootstrapper to update them.

```
  <Custom Action='RemoveServiceWithProvidedBatch' After='InstallInitialize'>Installed</Custom>

  <Custom Action='WaitForFileLocks' After='InstallInitialize'>Installed</Custom>

  <Custom Action='InstallService' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT REMOVE ~= "ALL"</Custom>

  <Custom Action='MergeConfigFiles' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT REMOVE ~= "ALL"</Custom>
```

Comment: to best place to start investigating this is a verbose log as always. Just look for the custom action name in it and there it should be written the reason why it is skipped  http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/get_a_log.html

Comment: Wix is non deterministic, there are very few things you can control the dequence over. You should be able to schedule your custom actions though, if you want MergeConfigFiles executed after your service install, change line 4 to: `<Custom Action='MergeConfigFiles' After='InstallService'>` If you're still  experiencing issues include an MSI log. It's probably an issue with your conditions.